# Fermat's last theorem -- Google and PCMag.com

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In recognition of Fermat's 410th birthday, Google ha(s/d) a special google-doodle with Fermat's last theorem.

The first link point(s/ed) to an [article on PCMag.com](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2391245,00.asp) which states:

> In time, Fermat was considered to be the founder of the modern number theory. He came up with Fermat's Last Theorem, which states that $x^n + y^n = z^n$.

Am I missing something or is the PCMag article missing something?

Comment: The article is missing something.

Comment: There is a good deal of uncertainty about the year Fermat was born.

Comment: Kudos for @oosterwal 's choice of an appropriate tag dripping with delicious irony.

Comment: Even the portrait is incorrect - it is Kepler, not Fermat. That's worse than the [Legendre portrait fiasco.](http://www.ams.org/notices/200911/rtx091101440p.pdf)

Comment: Which portrait?  The one at http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2391245,00.asp now is the same as in Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pierre_de_Fermat.jpg: maybe it has been changed.  However, I found a Kepler portrait labelled as Fermat at http://news.m3n4.com/general/2011/pierre-de-fermat

Comment: @Robert: See the comments in the article. It was changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PCMag is missing something. Fermat's Last Theorem is that for integers $x$, $y$, $z$, and $n$, with $n > 2$, $x^n + y^n \ne z^n$ (provided that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are nonzero).

Comment: ..provided $xyz\neq 0$. *trollface*

Comment: *trollface* didn't render correctly. Maybe you need $trollface$ :)

Comment: I fixed the post.

Answer (score 18):

PCMag's unreliability does not end there.  Later on in the same short article we have

"He died in the belief that he had found a relation which every prime must satisfy, namely $2^{2n}+1= \:\text{a prime}.$"

Then the article tells us that Euler disproved this by showing it was false at $n=5$.  Quite an achievement for Euler, showing that $1025$ is not prime!

Of course it should be $2^{2^n}+1$, not $2^{2n}+1$.

Also, "that every prime must satisfy" is wonderfully ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

The theorem should read,

> There do not exist nonzero integers $x, y, z$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for any $n>2$.